# I am trying to iterate over the return value of a function which returns a tuple of 3 tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, tuples, return-type

I have a 2 dimensional list called grid.

```
grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

A list of actions:

```
actlist = [1,2,3,4]
```

And a 2D list:

```
U = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

And a function called T, which takes 3 integer as argument.

```
def T(i,j,actions):
```

The function T looks like the following:
What this function does is, it takes i,j and actions and returns tuples of tuple like the following-

Now the problem is, when I'm trying to call the function inside a built-in sum function of python, within a for loop it's showing an error.

The error that it's showing is

My question is, how is it possible to get 3 tuples separately using a for loop, where I can use all the three values inside a tuple in each iteration.
And one thing, the following code is failing to take the individual values of three tuples.

Comment: what line is throwing the error?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is with the return value of the function. It returns a tuple of 3 tuples. And when I'm trying to iterate over the return value calling the function, it's showing the error that int object is not iterable.

Comment: `q_value = sum(U[k][l]*p for (k,l,p) in T(i,j,a))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `T` function sometimes returns a tuple of three tuples:

```
return (0,0,0.8),(1,0,0.1),(1,0,0.1)
```

… and sometimes just a tuple of three ints:

```
return (-1,-1,1)
```

When you try to iterate over the three values and unpack each one as a 3-tuple, sometimes those are going to be ints instead of 3-tuples. Which obviously isn't going to work.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you how to fix this, because I have no idea what this function is supposed to be doing. Maybe you wanted this:

```
return (-1,-1,1), (-1,-1,1), (-1,-1,1)
```

… or maybe this:

```
return (-1,-1,1),
```

… or maybe something entirely different. But I do know that you wanted to return some kind of iterable of 3-tuples.

---

But meanwhile, you have at least three other serious errors in your program.

First, what happens if none of those `elif` conditions is true? You just fall off the end of the function, which means you return `None`, which is not an iterable of 3-tuples.

Second:

```
elif(actions == "LEFT"):
```

All of your other tests are against some constant named `LEFT`. Unless that constant happens to have the value `'LEFT'`, this will not match.

Third:

```
if (actions == UP or DOWN or LEFT or RIGHT and i == 0 and j == 3):
```

… means:

```
if (actions == UP) or (DOWN) or (LEFT) or (RIGHT and i == 0 and j == 3):
```

Even if you fix the precedence issues by adding parentheses:

```
if actions == (UP or DOWN or LEFT or RIGHT) and i == 0 and j == 3:
```

… that still isn't useful, because `UP or DOWN or LEFT or RIGHT` is just the first one of those that's truthy (non-zero).

You probably wanted something like this:

```
if actions in {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT} and i == 0 and j == 3:
```

Comment: @AshishAcharya You're mistaken. Try `x, y, z = 1` at an interactive REPL: The OP isn't trying to index anything to do with the results of `T` anywhere, but he is trying to unpack each element of the result into a target list of 3 names.

Comment: @AshishAcharya Yes. And the `for` iterates that tuple of three things. And then, for each of the three things, it unpacks it into `(k,l,p)`. Which doesn't work if the thing is an `int`, because you can't iterable-unpack something that isn't iterable.

Comment: I tried the following code to take individual values of the three tuples.

`(k1,l1,p1) (k2,l2,p2) (k3,l3,p3) = T(i,j,a)`

Comment: @ShifatEArman Why would you expect it to? If your function sometimes returns a tuple of three ints, and sometimes returns `None`, how do you expect that code to work any better than your original code?